# Firebase Functions CORS blocking request

Tags: javascript, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, cors

I'm trying do deploy a http API on firebase functions but the CORS is blocking my request with Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
I wanted to use express but tried without it too, none of them worked.

The error i'm receiving is this:
[image: cors error]

With express:

```js
import cors from "cors";
import express from "express";

const app = express();
app.use(
    cors({
        origin: [
            "https://firebase-hosting-url.firebaseapp.com",
            "https://another-firebase-hosting-url.web.app",
            "https://example.com",
            "https://www.example.com",
            /\.example\.com$/,
        ],
    }),
);

app.post("/path", (req, res) => {
    //endpoint logic
});

exports.api = https.onRequest(app);
```

Without express:

```js
import cors from "cors";
import express from "express";

exports.api = https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const corsHandler = cors({
        origin: [
            "https://firebase-hosting-url.firebaseapp.com",
            "https://another-firebase-hosting-url.web.app",
            "https://example.com",
            "https://www.example.com",
            /\.example\.com$/,
        ],
    });

    corsHandler(req, res, () => {
        //endpoint logic
    });
});
```

Request on client:

```js
document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    fetch("https://firebase-functions-url.cloudfunctions.net/api/path", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: {
            //form data as json
        }
    })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => console.log(res))
        .catch(res => console.log(res));
})
```

Comment: Have you checked this documentation on [using existing Express apps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#using_existing_express_apps)?